# Unity, positioning with ints instead of floats

Tags: unity, floating-point

I round my transform.position to the nearest integer at the end of every frame so it's never a decimal number. I would like to know if there's a way to make unity store the position in ints instead of floats to prevent floating points precision problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that because Unity is doing all its internal calculation in `float`.

But if you would like to implement your game mechanics completely with integer arithmetics, you could write your own `Vector3Int` class, use it for all of your game mechanics, and then have each of your game objects write its Vector3Int-position to `transform.position` in `LateUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean a Vector3 type that uses `int`s, I don't think there is a type that uses ints as internal storage seeing as how the unity transform system all uses floats everywhere.