# How do I storage only integers value on a Vector3?

Tags: unity, c#

I need to figure out a way to lock or avoid Vector3 storage float numbers. I do need save only integers because each integer represents a place on an array. I don't wanna my objects moving with float precision. I need them moving on integer precision in world space (2D Game)

I tried force a type casting to round them up or down but it doesn't work

```
timeOffset += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timeOffset >= 0.75f)
    {
        Vector3 dir = playerCenter.transform.position - this.transform.position;
        transform.position += new Vector3((int)dir.x / dir.magnitude, (int)dir.y / dir.magnitude, 
            (int)dir.z / dir.magnitude);
        timeOffset = 0;
    }
```

[image: Unexpected results]

Any ideas?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never a good way to describe a problem. What happens instead of what you want?

Comment: That looks like an order of operations bug. (int)x/magnitude would convert x to an integer, then try to divide it by the float magnitude which converts it back to a float. Have you tried putting parentheses around the whole thing to convert the resulting dividend instead of the numerator? Or using Mathf.Round instead to save a redundant conversion to int and back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity, positioning with ints instead of floats](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131145/unity-positioning-with-ints-instead-of-floats)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not rounding the position, you're rounding only the input from the direction.

Instead of having this code for rounding:

```
transform.position += new Vector3(
    (int)dir.x / dir.magnitude, 
    (int)dir.y / dir.magnitude, 
    (int)dir.z / dir.magnitude);
```

Try this code:

```
transform.position += new Vector3(
    (int)(dir.x / dir.magnitude), 
    (int)(dir.y / dir.magnitude),  
    (int)(dir.z / dir.magnitude));
```

Notice that the type casting is done on the whole value that is set to the position, and not just partially (with the extra set of parenthesis).

---

Although this fixes your issue with keeping your positions as integer values, using the casting to int is probably not what you want, as the values in the range ]-1, 1[ will all be rounded to zero, which will result in weird behaviour near zero. You can use a method such as [`Mathf.Round`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html) or [`Mathf.RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html) (like DMGregory specified in his comment), or use a method like [`Mathf.Floor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Floor.html) or [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) to achieve a more constant behaviour.

I don't have access to Unity, but I've created a small set of data and applied the different actions on it in C#, here is the formatted result:

```
ValToStrng    cast to int    Round    Floor
-2.0         -2              -2       -2
-1.9         -1              -2       -2
-1.6         -1              -2       -2
-1.5         -1              -2       -2
-1.4         -1              -1       -2
-1.1         -1              -1       -2
-1.0         -1              -1       -1
-0.9          0              -1       -1
-0.6          0              -1       -1
-0.5          0               0       -1
-0.4          0               0       -1
-0.1          0               0       -1
 0.0          0               0        0
 0.1          0               0        0
 0.4          0               0        0
 0.5          0               0        0
 0.6          0               1        0
 0.9          0               1        0
 1.0          1               1        1
 1.1          1               1        1
 1.4          1               1        1
 1.5          1               2        1
 1.6          1               2        1
 2.0          2               2        2
```

Depending on your needs, you can apply the method that is most appropriate.

Comment: Well, nice point putting the expression in parenthesis, but now somehow the object is not updating its position, not moving. Before it moved inaccurate and unwanted way. Now not even moving is :/

Comment: @DouglasFerreira That's most likely because it does not move enough per frame, I suggest you spam the debug console with the values and their manipulation and see what's going on with it.

Comment: @DouglasFerreira I have added a bit more info, if it can help you a bit more :)